# Can anyone explain how this Codewars code works?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def validBraces(s):
 while '{}' in s or '()' in s or '[]' in s:
  s=s.replace('{}','')
  s=s.replace('[]','')
  s=s.replace('()','')
return s == ""
```

I found this code as a solution in codewars, or Validating Braces
I tried squishing my head still I can.t figure out how this works

On `print(validBraces(s))`, where s = `{[]}`
it returns `True`

But, when s = `{ab}`, it returns `False`.
Also, `replace("ab","#")` will only change `"ab"` (right?) and not `"a"` and `"b"`.

I'm a newbie and don't understand this. Can anyone explain?

Comment: It *only* works on strings that consist entirely of braces.

Comment: Try to run some valid/balanced as well as invalid braces in pythontutor.com

Comment: I guess that according to the statement it _should_ only work for strings that are braces-only (or you have to remove all non-braces chars first). It basically replaces pairs of braces from the inside outwards. Would be more efficient with a stack, though.

Comment: "replace("ab","#") will only change "ab" right? and not "a" and "b"" This is true, but it is also something easy for you to test on your own. What have you tried to validate this on your own?

Comment: The string `replace` function in Python doesn't use regex (the `re` module exists for that) so you are of course correct in your assumption that a replace input of `'ab'` will search for that exact match in a string (as opposed to `a` and then `b`)

Answer (score 1):

The python code works this way...

While there is the substring "{}", "()", or "[]"

1. replace all the occurrences of "{}" to "" (an empty string)
2. replace all the occurrences of "()" to an empty string
3. replace all the occurrences of "[]" to an empty string

If the string is now equal to an empty string, return True. Otherwise we return false.

> But, when s = {ab}, it returns False

If you mean that when `s = "{ab}"` then it will not result to an empty string because the code to replace the substring "ab" with an empty string is not in that while loop.

> Also, replace("ab","#") will only change "ab" right? and not "a" and "b"

Yes, it will only replace the literal occurrence of "ab" to "#" but not "a" or "b". For example...

`replace("ab", "#")`

- "{ab}" will change to "{#}"
- "{a}" will be unchanged
- "{b}" will be unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

The comparison inside the while condition check if the particular string in this case "{}" or "()" or "[]" if any of these are present then it is **Replaced** by "" which is empty. Technically replace something with "" means you are removing it, using the replace method in Python.

```
`return s == ""` after all the replacements are done the code checks if the finally updated string **s** is equal to "" or is **s** empty or not, if it is then it returns **True** else **False**

`replace("ab","#")` this will change all the "ab" in the given string variable and not separate **a** and **b**.
```

Example : s = "abba"        <- this variable s contains "abba"
s = s.replace("ab","t")      <- "ab" in the variable is replaced with "t" and a new string is returned because replace method return the modified string and not the original string itself.
now s is "tba"

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.